# GitHub actions conditional approval gates

Tags: github-actions

I am writing a workflow to deploy infrastructure to Azure using terraform. Authentication to each environment is done through using environments in GitHub, and each environment contains variables and secrets to perform the deployment.

Currently I have to approve the `terraform` job (below), which is fine. However, that plans *and* applies simultaneously without allowing a developer to view the plan that was produced.

What I would really like is to allow plan to run, and then only wait for approval for apply. However, this means I cannot use the environment in GitHub, because that will automatically require approval and then I will have two approval steps for each environment. I also want to be able to automatically display the plan in a PR comment whenever there are changes to terraform files.

The only way I can think of around this is to put all secrets and variables on the repository level and only use environments as gates.

How can I achieve this? Would you recommend me to approach this problem differently than what I am describing?

## Update

I managed to solve this, but not in a way I am particularly satisfied with because it forced my to use a PAT rather than the GitHub secret included in workflow runs. That token did not have access to reading variables, hence the PAT.

I've separated plan and apply into two separate jobs. The plan job has an additional step that reads variables from the environment:

```yaml
- name: Set environment context
  id: context
  env:
    GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}
  run: |
    vars=$(gh variable list --env ${{ matrix.env }})

    echo "$vars" | while read -r line; do
        if [[ -n $line ]]; then
            var_name=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
            var_value=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}')
            echo "Setting environment variable $var_name=$var_value"
            echo "$var_name=$var_value" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        fi
    done
```

When plan is done, it saves an artifact used by the apply job.

## Environments

### dev

[image: dev env config]

### prd

[image: prd env config]

### Workflow

```yaml
name: Terraform

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - "**.tf"
      - .github/workflows/deploy_infrastructure.yml
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      env:
        description: Environment to deploy to
        type: environment

permissions:
  id-token: write # Required for Azure login using federated credentials
  contents: read # Required for the checkout of code
  pull-requests: write # Required to write a PR comment

jobs:
  deployment-matrix:
    name: Set deployment matrix
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      matrix: ${{ steps.set-matrix.outputs.matrix }}
    steps:
    - id: set-matrix
      shell: bash
      run: |
        includes=()

        if [ "$GITHUB_EVENT_NAME" == "workflow_dispatch" ]; then
          includes+=('{"env": "${{ inputs.env }}"}')
        else
          includes+=('{"env": "dev"}')

          if [ "$GITHUB_REF_NAME" == "main" ]; then
            includes+=('{"env": "prd"}')
          fi
        fi

        includes_string=$(IFS=,; echo "${includes[*]}")
        deployments="{\"include\": [$includes_string]}"

        echo "Generated strategy matrix: $deployments"

        echo "matrix=${deployments}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

  terraform:
    name: Terraform
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs:
      - deployment-matrix
    strategy:
      matrix: ${{fromJson(needs.deployment-matrix.outputs.matrix)}}
      max-parallel: 1
    environment: ${{ matrix.env }}
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: terraform

    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Terraform
        uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v2

      - name: Azure Login
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.ARM_CLIENT_ID }}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.ARM_TENANT_ID }}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}

      - name: Format
        id: fmt
        run: terraform fmt -check
        continue-on-error: true

      - name: Init
        id: init
        run: |
          terraform init \
            -backend-config="resource_group_name=${{ vars.RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME }}" \
            -backend-config="storage_account_name=${{ vars.TF_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME }}" \
            -backend-config="client_id=${{ secrets.ARM_CLIENT_ID }}" \
            -backend-config="tenant_id=${{ secrets.ARM_TENANT_ID }}" \
            -backend-config="subscription_id=${{ secrets.ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}"

      - name: Validate
        id: validate
        run: terraform validate

      - name: Plan
        id: plan
        continue-on-error: true
        run: |
          terraform plan -var="environment=${{ matrix.env }}" -no-color -out=tfplan > /dev/null
          terraform show -no-color tfplan

      - uses: actions/github-script@v6
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        name: PR Comment
        with:
          github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          script: |
            const { data: comments } = await github.rest.issues.listComments({
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              issue_number: context.issue.number,
            });
            const botComment = comments.find(comment => {
              return comment.user.type === 'Bot' && comment.body.includes('Terraform summary')
            });

            if (botComment) {
              github.rest.issues.deleteComment({
                owner: context.repo.owner,
                repo: context.repo.repo,
                comment_id: botComment.id,
              });
            }

            const output = `# Terraform summary
            #### Terraform Format and Style \`${{ steps.fmt.outcome }}\`
            #### Terraform Initialization ⚙️\`${{ steps.init.outcome }}\`
            #### Terraform Plan \`${{ steps.plan.outcome }}\`
            #### Terraform Validation \`${{ steps.validate.outcome }}\`

            <details><summary>Show plan</summary>

            \`\`\`\n
            ${{ steps.plan.outputs.stdout }}
            \`\`\`

            </details>

            *Pushed by: @${{ github.actor }}, Action: \`${{ github.event_name }}\`*`;

            await github.rest.issues.createComment({
              issue_number: context.issue.number,
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              body: output
            })

      - name: Apply
        if: steps.fmt.outcome == 'success' && steps.plan.outcome == 'success'
        run: terraform apply tfplan
```